# IllegalArgumentException is thrown while calling a webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss, jaxb

We have a webservice whose implementation is done in .net. We are calling this webservice from java. The webservice responds perfectly normal on most scenarios but at times, it would throw IllegalArgumentException.

The webservice has two methods named pointEnquiry and pointEarnedEnquiry. Both these methods have an argument as pointEnquiryResult and pointEarnedEnquiryResult. The response wrapper is PointEnquiryResponse and PointsEarnedEnquiryResponse respectively.

The issue faced is that an IllegalArgumentException is thrown which states can not set PointEnquiryRespone.pointEnquiryResult to PointEarnedEnquiryResponse.

Also, the return type of both these methods is JAXBElement.

I am unable to understand how is the return type related to the wrapper classes and why pointEnquiryResult is trying to map itself to PointEarnedEnquiry response when it doesn't belong to that class.

Please find the stack trace

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceExcep`tion: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement field com.abc.xyz.PointEnquiryResponse.pointEnquiryResult to com.abc.xyz.PointEarnedEnquiryResponse   at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.handleRemoteException(ClientImpl.java:404)     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:172)  at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:152)  at $Proxy464.pointEarnedEnquiry(Unknown Source)     at com.hh.test.client.KioskService.pointEarnedEnquiry(CMPKioskService.java:118)     at com.hh.test.service.kioskInterface.KioskEndPointImpl.pointsEarnedEnquiry(KioskEndPointImpl.java:704)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2561.invoke(Unknown Source)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)   at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)   at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)   at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)   at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)   at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.aspects.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.java:166)  at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.java:115)     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)   at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)   at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)   at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:103)     at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:221)  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:466)  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:284)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:201)  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:134)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement field com.ballytech.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEnquiryResponse.pointEnquiryResult to com.ballytech.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEarnedEnquiryResponse    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)   at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)   at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)   at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:18)     at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.get(Accessor.java:231)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty$1.get(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:141)     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.getUnadapted(Accessor.java:147)     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$6.get(JAXBContextImpl.java:917)  at org.jboss.ws.metadata.accessor.JAXBAccessor.get(JAXBAccessor.java:50)    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.ParameterWrapping.unwrapResponseParameters(ParameterWrapping.java:226)  at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.syncOutputParams(CommonClient.java:510)   at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:396)     at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)

Please find more details :

Below is the code used to call the web service. It uses RPC style communication.

```
public PlayerPointsEnquiryParameter pointEnquiry(String playerId) throws Exception {
    PlayerPointsEnquiryParameter playerPointsEnquiryParameter  =null;
    try {
        if(iPointsEnquiry == null){
            URL wsdlURL = new URL(SWSUtility.getCMPPointEquiryURL());
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug("URL invoked : " + wsdlURL.toString());
            }
            Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL,_cmpPointEnqiry_QNAME);
            iPointsEnquiry = service.getPort(IPointsEnquiry.class);
        }
        
        playerPointsEnquiryParameter  = iPointsEnquiry.pointEnquiry(playerId);
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("playerPointsEnquiryParameter"+ playerPointsEnquiryParameter);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        iPointsEnquiry = null;
        logger.error("Malformed URL", e);
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        iPointsEnquiry = null;
        logger.error("Exception @", e);
        throw e;
    }
    return playerPointsEnquiryParameter;
}

public PlayerPointsEnquiryParameter pointEarnedEnquiry(String partonID, GregorianCalendar dtStartDate, GregorianCalendar dtEndDate ) throws Exception {
    PlayerPointsEnquiryParameter playerPointsEnquiryParameter  =null;
    try {
        XMLGregorianCalendar calenderdtStartDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dtStartDate);  
        XMLGregorianCalendar calendedtEndDater = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dtEndDate);
        if(iPointsEnquiry == null){
            URL wsdlURL = new URL(SWSUtility.getCMPPointEquiryURL());
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug("URL invoked : " + wsdlURL.toString());
            }
            Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL,_cmpPointEnqiry_QNAME);
            iPointsEnquiry = service.getPort(IPointsEnquiry.class);
        }
        
        playerPointsEnquiryParameter  = iPointsEnquiry.pointEarnedEnquiry(partonID, calenderdtStartDate, calendedtEndDater);
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("playerPointsEnquiryParameter"+ playerPointsEnquiryParameter);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.error("Malformed URL", e);
        iPointsEnquiry = null;
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception @", e);
        iPointsEnquiry = null;
        throw e;
    }
    return playerPointsEnquiryParameter;
}
```

Below is the implementation

```
public abstract interface IPointsEnquiry
{
  @WebMethod(operationName="PointEnquiry", action="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry/IPointsEnquiry/PointEnquiry")
  @WebResult(name="PointEnquiryResult", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry")
  @RequestWrapper(localName="PointEnquiry", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry", className="com.hhtechno.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEnquiry")
  @ResponseWrapper(localName="PointEnquiryResponse", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry", className="com.hhtechno.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEnquiryResponse")
  @Action(input="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry/IPointsEnquiry/PointEnquiry", output="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry/IPointsEnquiry/PointEnquiryResponse")
  public abstract PlayerPointsEnquiryParameter pointEnquiry(@WebParam(name="strPlayerId", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry") String paramString);

  
  @WebMethod(operationName="PointEarnedEnquiry", action="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry/IPointsEnquiry/PointEarnedEnquiry")
  @WebResult(name="PointEarnedEnquiryResult", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry")
  @RequestWrapper(localName="PointEarnedEnquiry", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry", className="com.hhtechno.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEarnedEnquiry")
  @ResponseWrapper(localName="PointEarnedEnquiryResponse", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry", className="com.hhtechno.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEarnedEnquiryResponse")
  @Action(input="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry/IPointsEnquiry/PointEarnedEnquiry", output="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry/IPointsEnquiry/PointEarnedEnquiryResponse")
  public abstract PlayerPointsEnquiryParameter pointEarnedEnquiry(@WebParam(name="strPlayerId", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry") String paramString, @WebParam(name="strStartDate", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry") XMLGregorianCalendar paramXMLGregorianCalendar1, @WebParam(name="strEndDate", targetNamespace="http://www.hhtechno.com/KioskPointsEnquiry") XMLGregorianCalendar paramXMLGregorianCalendar2);
}
```

The issue faced by me is that one of the threads lets say t1 is calling the methods pointEnquiry and waiting for the response. Meanwhile, another thread t2 comes into picture and calls pointsEarnedEnquiry. After a few seconds, thread t1 throws IllegalArgumentException as stated above.

I checked on the server end, for the request made by thread t1, an appropriate response is generated and sent.

My questions :

1. As the return type of both the webmethods in the web service are same i.e. PlayerPointsEnquiryMethod and I am not doing any kind of unwrapping at client end, why do I get an exception saying

   > Can not set javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement field com.hhtechno.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEarnedEnquiryResponse.pointEarnedEnquiryResult to com.hhtechno.kioskpointsenquiry.PointEnquiryResponse.
2. The difference in both the methods is the Request and Response Wrappers. While pointsEnquiry has the ResponseWrapper as PointsEnquiryResponse, pointsEarnedEnquiry has the ResponseWrapper as PointsEarnedEnquiryResponse. There must be something that indicates the unmarshaller to unwrap the response to PointsEarnedEnquiryResponse or PointsEnquiryResponse. Please guide me if I am wrong here.
3. The code works fine most of the times, it only throws IllegalArgumentException only a few times. Is this related to some caching problem?

Request the community's help as I have tried a lot and am at a dead end on how to proceed.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @lexicore Please find the added details. Request you to please help in understanding the problem.

Comment: @lexicore Added more points